# Disabling touch pad of Dell M6400

Tags: windows-7

How do I disable my Dell M6400 laptop touch pad?

Comment: "ouch pad"? *LOL* ;-)

Comment: I've fixed that typo - but it was funny!

Answer (score 1):

Look into the "Device Manager" and disable the device or check "Mouse" for options to turn it off. Also, expand the system tray, there you may find an icon for the touch pad where you can control it.

Answer (score 0):

According to Aaron Digulla's method, you'll be able to disable your touchpad only when an external mouse is attached. To disable your touchpad otherwise. install teh Synaptics touchpad drivers along with Scrybe, and you can do it from the system tray anytime. Bonus: You also get a host of multi-touch features!

Answer (score 0):

Physically disconnect it.  I forget if those are accessible from the top or bottom, but connection isn't too hard to get at.  If not looking for such a thorough disconnect, the bios likely has a setting that will disable the touchpad if a mouse is detected.